# Protect select statement from sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, strong-parameters

I recently stumbled across a part of the api, where a user can query specific fields:

```
api/models?only=id,name
```

It was implemented like this:

```
@model = Model.select params[:only]
```

With a quiet bad feeling about this line I tried if it is possible to inject sql into this part of the code ... and it worked.

After some thought we came up with this

```
@model = Model.select params[:only].split(',').map(&:to_sym)
```

This actually prevents the injection. But is this enough to secure this part of the API?

Is it possible to use strong parameters in this case?

```
query_params.require(:only).permit(:id,:name)
```

Does not work because the passed fields are a string and does not have the method `permit`.

Comment: you can send your params in headers.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything else. It is full proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, controllers are not supposed to utilize models' implementation details. The fact that values in SQL's select are comma-separated and your API accepts them as-is is a "coincidence" one shouldn't have relied on in the first place.

I'll introduce you to tools you might find useful in order to compose your solution.

```rb
# Array#&, set intersection
[1, 2, 3] & [2, 4, 1] # => [1, 2]

# Model.attributes
Model.attributes #=> ['id', 'name', ...]
# You can filter down the resulting array to produce a whitelist of columns

# Splat the array into the argument list
Model.select(*params[:only].split(',') & Model::SELECT_WHITELIST)
# ...the constant above has to be defined inside the model, obviously.
```

Comment: This seems to be a elegant way to do it. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize`

```
Model.select Model.sanitize(params[:only])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I looks like a good solution, but it's not working with the comma separated list in the example.